# Use SVG file as a logo on _Layout.chtml

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, svg

I have the following code in a `_Layout.chtml` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/styles")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")

        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="body-wrapper">

            <div class="header">
                <object data="~/Content/images/Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
            </div>

            <div class="main">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>            
        </div>  
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
</html>
```

The following code is my attempt to add an `SVG` file as a logo on top of the page.

```
            <div class="header">
                <object data="~/Content/images/Logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
            </div>
```

However, because I have done this, none of my `Views` will render.

Can someone point me into the right direction. I want to use a `SVG` image as a logo in the top left hand corner of all my pages. Then after the logo, the `View` for a requested page needs to render. How would I go to do this?

Comment: have you tried to use `Url.Content` or an `img` tag?

Comment: Just tried the `img` and that worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code fixed my problem:

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="~/Content/images/Logo.svg" /> 
</div>
```